# Can I restrict an Android application to be shown on Play Store only if remote target device supports vfp?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cpu-architecture

I only want to target devices those have armv6 + vfp cpu.

Is this kind of filter possible on Play Store?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to manually find every device that doesnt have armv6+vfp and exclude them from the supported devices section.

Comment: On Internet, do we a list which shows devices those support armv6 and/or vfp etc..?

Comment: I've checked the site and it only shows wheter the device is armv6 or not. We have no list that shows the vfp support of these devices. What do you think about a project that people contributes by just installing and opening the app for 1 time? This application would get cpu/brand/model info and cpu features and push it to a remote database. Wouldn't that be good?

Comment: Cant tell anything about this...i thought that you only need armv6 because you said "and/or vfp"

Comment: I need to filter out armv6 devices which do not have VFP :/

Comment: I found that manually disabling devices is not "always" possible as Google is not showing unpopular devices :/